# performing deduplication using flexible text matching in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have single column of address and I want to calculate levenshtein distance of all address in one column containing many address.

There are 40 address and I have to compare each address with eachother and find distance. Please help.

Comment: Hence for 40 addresses, you'll make 40*39 comaprisions, right?

Comment: aboslutely right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute Edit distance for a dataframe which has only column and multiple rows in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156739/compute-edit-distance-for-a-dataframe-which-has-only-column-and-multiple-rows-in)

Comment: it worked. what if I have multiple columns and I have to check for each coloum text similarity

Comment: you can ask a separate question regarding the new problem you are facing. Maybe, you can get answer from the members in a much better way.